# HTML / CSS can't understand something

Tags: php, html, css

i'm beginner with html / css , my question is why with the next html code :

The div for the second logo is not full grey and it's just 75% and more than that if i try to add in css #displayscore : if i wanna edit the value margin-top of margin_top everything will be scattered.

Like this:

[image]

I don't really know what to do , i tried everything and didn't find any solution on my problem. How it is possible that the first logo is full green and second is just 80% grey. And as i said when i try to margin_top the score i simply can't.

**CSS**:

[image]

**HTML**:

[image]

Comment: Post all code here directly. Never soley link to code.

Comment: I really tried but  the message " too much code " came up everytime

Comment: Preview line or jsfiddle link share here

Comment: @ApetreiAlin You have to share the minimum relevant code to reproduce the issue, not your entire application.

Comment: @ApetreiAlin  if my answer helped you, please accept it (by hovering beside it and clicking the checkmark.. thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I don't know how you got a 'too much code' error - there's not that much code!)

I added code to get rid of default added margin (You could also get rid of padding here; I suggest you add padding for the logos, left and right)

```
*{margin:0;}
```

I also aligned your divs to top

```
vertical-align:top;
```

As i used images found on the internet i inserted code to style them

```
div img{height:15px; width:auto;}
```

I displayed your divs `inline` but you can change this to suit your purposes (to inline-block or whatever)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top; 
}

#displaymatches2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
}

#displayhometeam2 {
  width: 65%;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  height: 70px;
}

#displayhometeam {
  width: 65%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#displayimagehome {
  width: 35%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: green;
}

#displayscore {
  width: 40%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: purple;
}

#displayawayteam {
  width: 30%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#displayimageaway {
  width: 35%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#displayawayteam2 {
  width: 65%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: orange;
}

div img {
  height: 15px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 1px 5px;    /*try this*/
}
```

```html
<div id="displaymatches2">
  <div id="displayhometeam">
    <div id="displayhometeam2">Steau
    </div>
    <div id="displayimagehome">
      <img src="https://hdlogo.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/steaua-bucuresti-logo.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="displayscore">
    0 - 4
  </div>

  <div id="displayawayteam">
    <div id="displayimageaway">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c0/FC_Dinamo_Bucuresti_logo.svg/502px-FC_Dinamo_Bucuresti_logo.svg.png">
    </div>
    <div id="displayawayteam2">
      Dinamo
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/tppgLn8o/)

Comment: added a touch of padding around the logos - try it

Comment: Happy to help! Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Thanks , it is maybe the best site for archieving knowledge and learning something .

Comment: Absolutely! No doubt!